# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac xn+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)^n = e^{-x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function

How can we mathematically precisely argue that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac xn+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)^n = e^{-x}$$ holds?

So how can we bring

$$1-\frac xn+\frac{x}{n^2} = 1- \frac{(n+1)x}{n^2} \approx 1 - \frac xn $$
and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac xn\right)^n=e^{-x}$$
together?

Or can we use this form somehow:
$$\left(1-\frac xn+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)^n 
= \left(\left( 1 - \frac{x}{\frac{n^2}{n+1}} \right)^{\frac{n^2}{n+1} }\right)^{\frac{n+1}{n}}$$

Comment: Yes, the last limit tends to $(e^{-x}) ^1 = e^{-x}$.

Comment: Take the logarithm and apply L'Hospital's rule ...

Comment: Is it possible to show that $\left( 1 + \frac{1}{a_n} \right)^{a_n} \to e$ for every arbitrary sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n \to \infty$ for $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @Heraklit If $a_n \to +\infty$ then $$
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{a_n }}} \right)^{a_n }  = \exp \left( {a_n \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{a_n }}} \right)} \right) = \exp \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{a_n }}} \right)} \right) = e\left( {1 +  \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{a_n }}} \right)} \right),
$$ since $\log (1 + x) = x + \mathcal{O}(x^2 )$, $\exp x = 1 + \mathcal{O}(x)$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257934, or this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1056863.

Comment: The last line you wrote is the way I would've gone about doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\dfrac xn+\dfrac x{n^2}\right)^n =\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{x(1-n)}{n^2}\right)^{\dfrac{n^2}{x(1-n)}}\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{nx(1-n)}{n^2}}$$

Now in the inner limit  set $\dfrac{x(1-n)}{n^2}=y\implies y\to0$

and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{nx(1-n)}{n^2}=x\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac1n-1\right)=?$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $ \left(\forall y\in\left(0,1\right)\right) $ : $$ y\leq-\ln{\left(1-y\right)}\leq\frac{y}{1-y} $$

That can be proven either using the main value theorem,, or studiing some functions.

Thus, setting $ y_{n}=\frac{x}{n}-\frac{x}{n^{2}} $, where $ x\in\mathbb{R} $, and $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $ being bigger enough so that $ y_{n}\in\left(0,1\right) $. We get : $$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{x}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq -\ln{\left(1-\frac{x}{n}+\frac{x}{n^{2}}\right)}\leq\frac{\frac{x}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}{1-\frac{x}{n}+\frac{x}{n^{2}}}\\ \iff \frac{-x\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)}{1-\frac{x}{n}+\frac{x}{n^{2}}}\leq\ln{\left(1-\frac{x}{n}+\frac{x}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}}\leq -x\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) $$

Taking $ n $ to $ +\infty $, we get that : $$ \ln{\left(1-\frac{x}{n}+\frac{x}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}-x $$

Which means : $$ \left(1-\frac{x}{n}+\frac{x}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\mathrm{e}^{-x} $$

Answer (score 0):

When $L=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}\to 1^{\infty}$, then
$L=\exp[\lim_{x\to a} g(x) [f(x)-1]$
$$K=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac xn+\frac{x}{n^2}\right)^n  $$
$$K=\exp[ \lim_{x \to \infty} n [1-x/n+x^2/n^2-1]]=\lim_{x \to \infty} -x+x/n=e^{-x}$$

Comment: The notation $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)}\to 1^{\infty}$ makes no sense, the left-hand side is a number independent of $x$.